# What is the best diet for healthy eyesight?

Tags: eye-strain

I work in front of computer a lot, read books and drive. I wear glasses and their number keeps growing. Every year when my eyes become strained I know I need new lenses. I get breaks from the computer every hour or two. Is there any other advice besides diet? Thanks.

Comment: Just an advice: While looking at computer, try to close and open your eyes(i.e winking with both eyes) every 3-10 minutes. It helps to reduce strain on eyes.

Comment: Another advice: i know surrounding oneself with screens is sexy, but try to have distant target to look at every now and then to also reduce stress of eye muscles, helps a lot if you have a window near by or a long hallway for example.